# Something like Parallel.ForEach File.Readling - but instead of readline, read from specified indexes?

Tags: c#, string, performance, parallel-processing, text-files

I have huge textfiles (1GB+). So I was thinking if something like the following would be possible:

- ReadFile and create an int array with starting indexes / positions
- Use Parallel.ForEach to read the file starting with all the indexes until you arrive at the next index or a specific character

**Example**:

Textfile:

```
"I am a test file. Please use me. You used me. Urraaaaaaaaaay!"

int array = {0,10,20};
```

Parallel.ForEach with 3 threads:

1. ReadFile starting with character at 0 to 9
2. ReadFile starting with character at 10 to 19
3. ReadFile starting with character at 20 to end

1 GB is just one file. We get one such file every 10s 24/7.

Comment: Unless you're doing something CPU intensive with the data, I don't see much point. The bottleneck in reading a file is not the CPU, it's the HDD.

Comment: I also suggest to take a look at this:  http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files

Comment: I agree with @Rotem , that being said, innovation is awesome, give it a try, and let us know how it works out.

Comment: You are right. I forgot the HDD is the bottleneck. Not the CPU. Right now I am first going through the file removing and adding RETURNS, and after that I use the standard Parallel.ForEach with ReadLine.

Comment: 1GB is NOT HUGE.

Comment: 1GB is just one file. We get one such file every 10s 24/7.

Comment: Consider using [pipelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx) instead. This will give you a good parallelization of CPU-intensive operations without jerking the heads of hard drives here and there.

Comment: Also read [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/sequential-file-programming-patterns-and-performance-with-net/#) document. Please note item 2 in the Summary: _Pre-allocate large sequential files when the file is created. This typically
improves speed by about 13% when compared to a fragmented file_. This partially eliminates bottleneck hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

A parallel for loop will speed up reading from large text files. Given you're getting a 1GB file every 10 seconds 24/7, it would be worthwhile implementing a [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) loop.

David Lozinski ran [many tests](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files) <sup>(1)</sup> on reading text files and then compared [parallelism to regular for loops](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files) *(all the examples are taken or adapted from  David Lozinski.)*.

For text file with lines length equivalent to 5 GUIDs (160 chars) it was faster to use `ReadAllLines` to add the text to an array.

For example:

```
AllLines = new string[MAX]; //only allocate memory here
AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

For text files with longer lines (> 10 GUIDs or 320 chars) it's marginally faster to use `ReadLine` and with or without a `BufferedStream` to create the array.

```
AllLines = new string[MAX]; //only allocate memory here
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    int x = 0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
           AllLines[x] = sr.ReadLine();
           x += 1;
    }
} // The using will dispose of any resources.
```

The the array is then processed within the Parallel For loop.

```
Parallel.For(0, AllLines.Length, x =>
{
    YourFile Processing(AllLines[x]);
});
```

This should make processing time significantly faster, although this will also depend on the machine running the program, it's CPU and how many threads are available to propagate the parallel processes.

<sup>(1)</sup> Thanks to [jason.kaisersmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847962/jason-kaisersmith) for this link in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462017/something-like-parallel-foreach-file-readling-but-instead-of-readline-read-fr#comment77884713_45462017)